# Using cerberus in Python to validate boolean values

Tags: python, validation, boolean, schema, cerberus

I'm trying to use Cerberus in Python to validate some data.
I found out that for 'boolean' type, the validator always return True, like this:

```
import cerberus
bool_schema = {'name': {'type': 'boolean', 'required': True}}
cerberus.schema_registry.add('bool_schema', bool_schema)

v = cerberus.Validator({'name': {'schema': 'bool_schema'}})
test1 = {'name': 'a'}
test2 = {'name': 0}
print(v.validate(test1))
print(v.validate(test2))
```

The above code prints two Trues.
Actually, what I need is to validate if the value is True or False (bool type in Python), other values should not pass the validator.

Comment: What version of `cerberus` are you using? the above code causes an error ("`raise SchemaError(self.schema_validator.errors)
cerberus.schema.SchemaError: {'name': [{'schema': [{'anyof': ['no definitions validate', {'anyof definition 1': ['Rules set definition boolean not found.'], 'anyof definition 0': ['Schema definition boolean not found.']}]}]}]}`" with `cerberus` 1.0.1 which is the latest.

Comment: I installed `cerberus` through `pip` and the `cerberus.__version__` shows it is precisely version 1.0.1

Comment: Sorry, I wrote something wrong in the question, the schema name in `Validator` is `'bool_schema'` not `'schema'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a semantically issue. Though you didn't specify explicitly what you want to achieve, I'm assuming you want to test whether the value mapped to `name` in a dictionary is a boolean and ensure it is present.

In line 4 of your example code you're defining a schema that refers to a previously defined schema from a schema registry. While validation it will be interpreted as

```
{'name': 
    {'schema': {
       {'type': 'boolean',
        'required': True}
}}}
```

The second-level `schema` rule will only be processed [if the value of `name` is a mapping](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#schema-dict). In each of your examples this is not the case, which will effectively process no rule at all and thus the validation returns `True` each time.

In order to answer the question I assumed above, this will cover it:

```
import cerberus
required_boolean = {'type': 'boolean', 'required': True}
cerberus.rules_set_registry.add('required_boolean', required_boolean)
v = cerberus.Validator({'name': 'required_boolean'})
```

Comment: I see. `schema_registry` means to validate the whole **dict** on that position.

Answer (score 2):

Might be an issue with the schema registry (I opened a [ticket](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/cerberus/issues/295) so we can investigate it further - will report back here).

In the meantime, you can skip the registry and it will work just fine:

```
from cerberus import Validator

schema = {'name': {'type': 'boolean', 'required': True}}

v = Validator()
v.validate({'name': 'a'})
False

v.errors
{'name': ['must be of boolean type']}
```

EDIT for future readers: the answer from @funky-future below actually explains why your code was failing, and how to fix it.

Comment: maybe it'd be better to delete this answer?